# Compress and uncompress objects in java if they resides in different packages

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

Here is the way i compress java objects and uncompress object back to the given class object.

**Compress code snippet**

```
public <T extends Serializable> byte[] compress(T  obj){

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        SnappyOutputStream sos=new SnappyOutputStream(baos);
        ObjectOutputStream objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(sos);
        objectOut.writeObject(obj);
        objectOut.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

**Uncompress code snippet**

```
public <T extends Serializable> T uncompress(byte[] srcByteArray,
        Class<T> type) {

    ObjectInputStream objectIn = null;
    T obj = null;
    try {
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(srcByteArray);
        SnappyInputStream sis = new SnappyInputStream(bais);
        objectIn = new ObjectInputStream(sis);
        obj = type.cast(objectIn.readObject());
    } catch (Exception e) {

        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    return obj;

}
```

Compress and uncompress worked if the compress class and uncompress class object resides in same package.

Eg:
**SampleVO.java**

```
package com.mypro.client.vo;
class SampleVO implements Serializable{
   instance fields...
   getter and setters
}
```

**Usage**

```
//SampleVO.java resides in  com.mypro.client.vo package
byte[] ar=compress(new SampleVO());
SampleVO s=uncompress(ar,SampleVO.class);
```

In my requirement i have client server communication what it does client compress `SampleVO.java`(resides in `com.mypro.client.vo package`) class and post object to server.communication happend via `REST` endpoints.

When server received compress byte stream and uncompressed obj back into same class type(SampleVO.java) but resides in different package.(`com.mypro.server.vo`).When processing it thorws `classNotfoundException com.mypro.client.vo.SampleVO`.

To overcome issue i renamed server side package into match the client side package and then it worked(`com.mypro.server.vo into com.mypro.client.vo`).

But i feel like this is not the elegant way to achieve that.reason is that can have multiple compress objects communicate with server side and then i have to renamed all packages to match the client packages.

So my question is that how can i compress java object and uncompress back to given class type if they resides in different package and different projects.

**Note:Client and server are separate maven projects.**

Comment: In java a class is defined by unqualified name + package. So for java it is different packages => different classes, no way around it! Why would your server-side packages differ from the client-side ones? There seems something broken in your design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you should have THREE packages, not two.  One for the server, one for the client, and an independent package/project for the data model, which does not belong to either the client or the server.

The data model package is then a dependency of both the server and the client.